# Solr Custom parser issue

Tags: solr

I want to have a simply functionality of matching entire user query with the indexed data and return only the exact matches. I know we could give the query within double quotes. But since this utility is going to be used widely in our application, I designed a custom parser component which would create a phrase query for the user entered query (just like how solr does when the query is given inside double quotes).

But in this case I am unable to get any documents as matches.

The code is:

```
public Query parse() throws ParseException {

    PhraseQuery pq = new PhraseQuery();
    String qf = params.get("qf",getReq().getSchema().getDefaultSearchFieldName());
    String query = getString();

    if(query == null){
        return pq;      
    }
    String[] queryTerms = query.split("[ ?<>,/?\\()*!@#$%^&_+=|{}'`~;:\"-.]");
    for(String queryTerm : queryTerms){
        pq.add(new Term(qf,queryTerm.toLowerCase()));   
    }

    return pq;
}
```

Any suggestions please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to write a custom implementation ?
Extending the `QueryParserHelper` class and modifying the query before calling should work for you, as it would create a phrase query.

Prototype -

```
@Override
public Query parse(String query, String defaultField)
    throws QueryNodeException {
  String modifiedQuery = "\""+query.toLowerCase()+"\"";
  return (Query) super.parse(modifiedQuery, defaultField);

}
```

Comment: I have tried the same but my custom method didn't get call can you please let me  know why this is not called .i have also asked same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431700/queryparserhelper-sub-classe-not-called .please have a look